# Are amino acids of viruses L or D enantiomers?

Tags: virology, amino-acids

I read a note saying that the amino acids of viruses are D enantiomers but I can't understand how that's possible since their human host can't even recognize that type.

Comment: The explanation here is way more prosaic than you suppose: the note is wrong.

Comment: @vkehayas I approved your edit but I kept the reference to the mysterious "note".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's apparently based on a complete misunderstanding. Unless the person can post the "note" that ostensibly makes this claim, there's no utility for SE.bio site here.

Answer (score 2):

Viral amino acids would almost exclusively be L-enantiomers considering they use host cell resources and machinery to build their proteins and the host cells are built on L-enantiomers.

With that said, you could always have nonstandard exceptions as xusr mentioned, if a virus somehow requires oxidase for example.